# Does anyone know a date format called orpheus? How can I convert it with transact sql?

Tags: sql-server, date, converters

I have a "shitty" application here which uses a date format called orpheus.

How can I convert this format to a readable date/time format?

For example: The date 2017-07-24 is in orpheus: 152511

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Edit: Found something... It uses "DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) + 109573" to convert the current date into orpheus. But I can't believe it is just such as simple?

Finally I found/modified a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[func_OrpheusToDate]
(
    @stDate as integer
)
RETURNS date
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @sql_date_tmp DATE = NULL;
DECLARE @lyear   INTEGER;
DECLARE @lmonth  INTEGER;
DECLARE @lday    INTEGER;
DECLARE @sdatstr VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @i       INTEGER;
DECLARE @j       INTEGER;

IF (@stDate IS NULL) OR (@stDate <= 0) OR (@stDate >= 999999) 
    SET @sql_date_tmp = NULL
ELSE IF (@stDate <= 59)
BEGIN
    SET @sql_date_tmp = GETDATE();
    SET @lyear = 1600;

    IF (@stDate <= 30)
    BEGIN
        SET @lmonth = 1;
        SET @lday   = @stDate +1;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @lmonth = 2;
        SET @lday   = @stDate -30;     
    END;

    SET @sdatstr = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @lyear) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @lmonth) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @lday);
    SET @sql_date_tmp = CONVERT(DATE, @sdatstr);
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @sql_date_tmp = GETDATE();

    SET @i = (4*(@stDate -59))-1;

    SET @j = (4*ROUND((@i % 146097)/4, 0,1))+3
    SET @lyear = (100*ROUND(@i/146097, 0, 1))+ROUND(@j/1461, 0, 1)

    SET @i = (5*ROUND(((@j % 1461)+4)/4, 0, 1))-3;
    SET @lday = ROUND(((@i % 153)+5)/5, 0, 1);

    SET @lmonth = ROUND(@i/153, 0, 1);

    IF (@lmonth < 10)
        SET @lmonth = @lmonth +3
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @lmonth = @lmonth -9;
        SET @lyear = @lyear +1;
    END;

    SET @lyear = @lyear + 1600;

    SET @sdatstr = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @lyear) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @lmonth) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @lday);

    SET @sql_date_tmp = CONVERT(DATE, @sdatstr);
END

RETURN @sql_date_tmp
END
```

Should be working

Edit:

Better Solution (Thanks to Jeroen Mostert):

```
DATEADD(DAY, @stDate, CONVERT(DATE, '1600-01-01'))
```

Comment: I didn't find anything... can you also tag 'orpheus' ? or put up some more info, like logic behind orpheus date format?

Comment: If I do `SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -152511, SYSDATETIME())` I get `1600-07-30 13:24:53.2045888`, which suggests it's using an era of `1600-01-01`. Sure enough: `SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 152511, CONVERT(DATE, '1600-01-01'))` -> `2017-07-24`. (I don't know Orpheus at all, so this is just a simple reverse engineered guess. It'll be more difficult if you involve time.)

Comment: I found something inside the Code of this application. It uses this "function" to get the current date to an orpheus format: DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) + 109573

Comment: That's ugly code, using the fact that SQL Server's era is `1900-01-01` and the integer `0` converts to this (and no doubt written before `DATE` existed, since `DATETIME` doesn't support `1600-01-01` as a value). But hey, it works. `109573`, is, of course, `SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '1600-01-01', '1900-01-01')`.

Comment: The source of the format seems to be [TurboPower Orpheus](https://github.com/TurboPack/Orpheus) (an UI toolkit) made by TurboPower software. There's source code on GitHub that includes the date handling part and states that the date type is stored as and integer indicating days since 1600-01-01. See more here: https://github.com/TurboPack/Orpheus/blob/master/source/OvcDate.pas

Comment: I didn't read the whole source.... Can I work with this "+109573" - "function" to get my date formats? Or are there some issues regarding leapyear etc.?

Comment: There won't be problems with leap years. Are you using `date` or `datetime` or `datetime2`?

Comment: I am using date in this case. Just to know: are there any problems using datetime?

Comment: That function is absurdly overcomplicated. `SELECT DATEADD(DAY, @stDate, CONVERT(DATE, '1600-01-01'))` has the same output, except for values <= 60, where the function fails to do anything meaningful unless your locale happens to be European. Don't use it; it was written by someone who very clumsily translated the Pascal code into its literal T-SQL equivalent, ignoring the fact that `DATEADD` already exists.

Comment: The main issue you'll run into with `DATETIME` is that it does not support dates before `1753-01-01`, which is no problem if you're not actually using such dates, but complicates calculations a little because you can't directly use `1600-01-01` (the starting era for Orpheus). `DATE` and `DATETIME2` don't have this problem as they can represent anything from `0001-01-01` upwards.